# Bash Scripting, reading an indefinite number of integers and applying formulas

Tags: bash

I just started learning bash. I know there are advanced ways of solving this problem but I can't use any advanced methods. I recently finished a lecture on loops and I'm expected to know how to solve this. But after 3+ hours of reading I can't find a solution.

Here's the prompt:
Create a script that will take in x amount of numbers from a user (minimum 5 numbers) via the use of positional variables. Then do the following:

- Count how many numbers were inputted
- Add up all the numbers
- Multiply all the numbers
- Find the average of all the numbers

```
read -p "Enter at least 5 integers"

#Check to make sure integers entered are indeed integers (how?)
#Check to make sure at least 5 integers were entered (how?)

#for total number of integers entered, add into a sum
#for total number of integers entered, find total product
#find average of all integers entered
```

My main issues are with the checks. Also, how do I assign an indefinite number of values to variables? Thanks for any help. I've looked around but have found no beginner solution to this.

Comment: Are you allowed to use arrays?

Comment: No unfortunately. I have not learned the usage of arrays in bash

Comment: What is meant by *positional variables*?

Comment: My guess is it means the command-line parameters to the script, like `$1`, `$2`, etc. So you're not supposed to use `read`.

Comment: Possibly. In my book some positional variables include $# and $#

Comment: What @Barmar says makes sense. Then you have access to `$#` for the number of parameters, you can easily iterate through all of them using the argument list `$@` etc.

Comment: The usual way to iterate through the argument list is by using `$1` and `shift`.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to implement such an iteration. Maybe using a for loop and making sure the counter is less than or equal to $#? How would I sum the values afterwards?

Comment: You can do like this, for example: `for num in $@; do echo $num; done`. Instead of `echo` do some processing, of course.

Comment: @fanton, always quote `"$@"` in a for loop -- otherwise arguments containing whitespace will be split. Similarly, quote the loop variable: `echo "$num"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i sum=0
declare -i counter=0
declare -i product=1
if [[ $# -lt 5 ]]
then
    echo "Please enter atleast 5 positional parameters"
    exit 1
fi

for num in "$@"     #$@ means all positional parameters, $1, $2, $3 and so on 
do
#checking if the entered positional parameters are digits using regular expression, [0-9]+ means match any digit 1 or more times
    if [[ "$num" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
    then
        sum=$(($sum+$num))
        product=$(($product*$num))
        ((counter++))
    else
        echo "$num is not a number"
    fi
done
echo 
echo "Result: "
echo "count of numbers: $counter"
echo "sum of numbers: $sum"
echo "average of numbers: "$(echo "scale=4;$sum/$counter" | bc)
echo "product of numbers: $product"
```

Output:

```
$ ./script.bash 1 2 3 4 5 abcd
abcd is not a number

Result: 
count of numbers: 5
sum of numbers: 15
average of numbers: 3.0000
product of numbers: 120

$ ./script.bash 1 2 3 
Please enter atleast 5 positional parameters

$ ./script.bash 56 78 235 67 466

Result: 
count of numbers: 5
sum of numbers: 902
average of numbers: 180.4000
product of numbers: 32048758560
```

Comment: `$[...]` is undocumented. Please use `$((...))` as [documented here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

Comment: Thanks. In the future, for what are clearly homework questions, don't give a complete answer, but give hints and links to documentation so the person can learn

Comment: I know this site encourages learning rather than just solving the problem for the person, but seeing how others do it really helps. Many thanks to everyone!